# The constant of integration in the solution to the differential equation $-4 g(x)=2 x g'(x)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

When I solved this differential equation---

> $$-4 g(x)=2 x g'(x)$$

---I obtained

$$\log (g(x))=-2 \log (x).$$ Solving for g(x) I got $\frac{1}{x^2}$.

Now this is an error that I constantly manage to get, and I do not understand how I can overcome this mistake. The first mistake here is that I have no constant. Now when using mathematica I get $\frac{c}{x^2}$, where c is the constant. I have been told that I should add the constant and not multiply it. However this is clearly not correct for all cases. Second  the solution I made is conditional. 
$$-\pi <-2 \Im(\log (x))\leq \pi$$

My question is, how can I make sure that I get the constant in correct form(multiply or add or subtract etc.) Second I would like to know how a mathematician would know that this would be conditional. Is there an intuition they have, do they check it by graphing?

Comment: I am happy to make any changes to the question, not sure why it is voted down!

Comment: How did you acheive that solution?

Comment: Rearranging and integrating both sides. Are saying that its necessary to show that in the question?

Comment: Well, that's probably why someone downvoted you. When asking for help people might want to see what you did wrong, and they can only do that if they have the steps you followed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You rearrange this separable equation as

$$ \dfrac{d}{dx} \log(g) = \dfrac{g'}{g} = \dfrac{-2}{x} = \dfrac{d}{dx} (-2 \log x)$$
(assuming for the moment $x$ and $g$ are positive: the other cases are similar).
Then taking antiderivative of both sides introduces an arbitrary constant:

$$ \log(g) = -2 \log(x) + c $$

and taking exponential of both sides

$$ g = e^c e^{-2 \log(x)} = \dfrac{C}{x^2} $$
where $C = e^c$.

There is no "conditional".  This solution works for any $C$, as you can see by substituting it into the differential equation.

Comment: Cant believe that my sloppiness of not writing the constant until the end by adding it, is the reason to all my problems! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Rearranging shows that the equation is separable: Provided that $g(x)$ is nowhere $0$, we have
$$\phantom{(ast)} \qquad \frac{g'(x)}{g(x)} = -\frac{2}{x}. \qquad (\ast)$$
The left hand side is $\frac{d}{dx}\log g(x),$ so integrating gives
$$\log g(x) = \int - \frac{2}{x} dx = - 2\log|x| + C.$$
In particular, we've absorbed the constant of integration that occurs on the l.h.s. into $C$, which in turn gives rise to the parameter in the general solution to the o.d.e. $(\ast)$.

Mathematica mentions the additional equation you've called a condition because it tacitly assumes that you're interested in *complex* solutions, which is presumably not the case here; in fact, it's simply reporting a so-called choice of branch cut for the logarithm function, but this has no consequence for the general condition. Indeed, for any choices $C \in \Bbb C$, one can check by substitution that $g(z) := \frac{C}{z^2}$ is a solution.

Comment: Thank you for the additional mathematica comment!

Comment: You're welcome. As I recall there's a way to assert to Mathematica that you're just looking for real solutions (or working with real objects more generally), which should suppress these sorts of irrelevant remarks when you don't want them.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**:Let $y = g(x)$, then the equation becomes: $-4y = 2xy' \to xy'=-2y \to x\dfrac{dy}{dx} = -2y \to \dfrac{dy}{y}=-\dfrac{2dx}{x}$. Can you complete the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose for now that $g \not\equiv 0$. If we have $$-4 g(x)=2 x g'(x),$$ we can rewrite this as: $$\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{-2}{x}.$$Integrating both sides: $$\int \frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}\,{\rm d}x = \int \frac{-2}{x}\,{\rm d}x \implies \ln|g(x)| = -2\ln |x|+c = \ln(1/x^2)+c, \quad c \in \Bbb R.$$ So taking exponentials: $$|g(x)| = e^{\ln(1/x^2)+c} = e^c\frac{1}{x²} = \frac{C}{x^2}, \quad C > 0.$$Getting rid of the absolute value: $$g(x) = \frac{C}{x^2}, \quad C \in \Bbb R \setminus \{0\}.$$ Since $g \equiv 0$ is also a solution, we write all together: $$g(x) = \frac{C}{x^2}, \quad C \in \Bbb R.$$